# taking out elements separately within an element using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The structure of the website data is as follows:

tiles

-> a

--> div

--> div

------> content

-----------> **p**

-----------> **p**

-----------> **p**

--> div

--> div

```
def grabData(url):

    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np


    my_url = url

    #opening up the connection, grabbing the page
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    #html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    #grabs each item
    tiles = page_soup.findAll('div', {'class':'category-tile-grid-item'})

    for tile in tiles:
        content_container = tile.findAll('div',{'class':'shop-tile__content--border-bottom'})
        store_name = content_container[0].text
        print(store_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grabData('https://exchange.shopify.com/shops?sale_price=1000&shopify_shop_created_at=6m%2C0m')
```

I am looking to retrieve the paragraph values separately. How can I go about doing this?

---

EDIT:

I have updated my code as per **orhan solak**

```
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import pandas as pd

start_urls = ["https://exchange.shopify.com/shops", "https://exchange.shopify.com/shops?sale_price=1000&shopify_shop_created_at=6m%2C0m", "https://exchange.shopify.com/shops?sale_price=1000&shopify_shop_created_at=6m%2C0m"]

def shopify_exchange_data(url):

    url_list = []
    category_list = []
    title_list = []
    value_list = []
    traffic_list = []
    revenue_list = []

    for link in start_urls:
       # Getting the webpage, creating a Response object.
        response = requests.get(link,proxies=None)
        # Extracting the source code of the page.
        data = response.text

        first_class_name = "'grid grid--equal-height'"
        second_class_name = "'grid__item grid__item--tablet-up-third grid__item--desktop-up-quarter grid__item--wide-up-quarter gutter-bottom category-tile-grid-item layout-flex'"
        # We'll iterate this second class for 24 times.
        third_class_name = "'shop-tile__price'"
        # this is value xpath
        fourth_class_name = "'shop-tile__url heading--truncated'"
        title_class_name = "'shop-tile__title heading--truncated'"
        category_class_name = "'shop-tile__category heading--truncated'"
        # this is name xpath
        fifth_class_name = "'shop-tile__data shop-tile__data--has-graph'"
        revenue_class_name = "'shop-tile__data shop-tile__data--has-graph'"
        # this is traffic xpath
        for i in range(1,25):

            url_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class="+first_class_name+"]//div[@class="+second_class_name+"]["+str(i)+"]//p[@class="+fourth_class_name+"])"
            test_url = Selector(text=data).xpath(url_xpath).extract()[0]
            url_list.append('http://'+test_url)

            title_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class=" + first_class_name + "]//div[@class=" + second_class_name + "][" + str(i) + "]//p[@class=" + title_class_name + "])"
            test_title = Selector(text=data).xpath(title_xpath).extract()[0]
            title_list.append(test_title)

            category_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class=" + first_class_name + "]//div[@class=" + second_class_name + "][" + str(i) + "]//p[@class=" + category_class_name + "])"
            test_category = Selector(text=data).xpath(category_xpath).extract()[0]
            category_list.append(test_category)

            traffic_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class="+first_class_name+"]//div[@class="+second_class_name+"]["+str(i)+"]//div[@class="+fifth_class_name+"]/span)"
            test_traffic = Selector(text=data).xpath(traffic_xpath).extract()[0]
            test_traffic = test_traffic[1:]
            traffic_list.append(test_traffic)

            revenue_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class="+first_class_name+"]//div[@class="+second_class_name+"]["+str(i)+"]//div[@class="+fifth_class_name+"]/span)"
            test_revenue = Selector(text=data).xpath(revenue_xpath).extract()[0]
            test_revenue = test_revenue[1:]
            revenue_list.append(test_revenue)

            value_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class=" + first_class_name + "]//div[@class=" + second_class_name + "][" + str(i) + "]//div[@class=" + third_class_name + "])"
            test_value = Selector(text=data).xpath(value_xpath).extract()[0]
            value_list.append(test_value)

    # print(len(value_list))
    # print(len(name_list))
    # print(len(traffic_list))
    #
    #
    # print(value_list[:24])
    # print(name_list[:24])
    # print(traffic_list[:24])

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['title'] = title_list
    df['url'] = url_list
    df['category'] = category_list
    df['traffic'] = traffic_list
    df['revenue'] = revenue_list
    df['price'] = value_list
    df.to_csv('test.csv', sep=",")

    print (df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    shopify_exchange_data(start_urls)
```

I now would like to figure out how to get Revenue amongst other values within the metrics container.  How do I go about doing this? Why is this selecting traffic instead of revenue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to you use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) for extracting data with a specific Xpath. I checked your code and the Xpath is a little bit wrong. I have reconfigured your code. I assigned the class's names to a variable. After that I combined them to create an **exact xpath**. In following code sample; I created 7 lists that contains respectively **price**, **name**, **website type**, **revenue**, **traffic**, **profit**,**inventory value** .

```
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector

start_urls = ["https://exchange.shopify.com/shops?sale_price=1000&shopify_shop_created_at=6m%2C0m"]
price_list = []
name_list = []
website_type_list = []

revenue_list = []
traffic_list = []
profit_list = []
inventory_value_list = []

for link in start_urls:
   # Getting the webpage, creating a Response object.
    response = requests.get(link,proxies=None)
    # Extracting the source code of the page.
    data = response.text

    first_class_name = "'grid grid--equal-height'"
    second_class_name = "'grid__item grid__item--tablet-up-third grid__item--desktop-up-quarter grid__item--wide-up-quarter gutter-bottom category-tile-grid-item layout-flex'"
    # We'll iterate this second class for 24 times.

    third_class_name = "'shop-tile__price'"
    # this is price xpath

    fourth_class_name = "'shop-tile__url heading--truncated'"
    # this is name xpath

    fifth_class_name = "'shop-tile__content shop-tile__metrics-container'"
    # this is table xpath (from Revenue (USD) to Inventory Value)

    sixth_class_name = "'shop-tile__metric'"
    # this is all four row's xpath in the table. We'll iterate this four times from revenue to Inventory Value

    seventh_class_name = "'shop-tile__category heading--truncated'"
    # this is website's type (automative, sports etc.)

    for i in range(1,25):

        price_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class="+first_class_name+"]//div[@class="+second_class_name+"]["+str(i)+"]//div[@class="+third_class_name+"])"
        test_price = Selector(text=data).xpath(price_xpath).extract()[0]
        price_list.append(test_price)

        name_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class="+first_class_name+"]//div[@class="+second_class_name+"]["+str(i)+"]//p[@class="+fourth_class_name+"])"
        test_name = Selector(text=data).xpath(name_xpath).extract()[0]
        name_list.append(test_name)

        website_type_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class="+first_class_name+"]//div[@class="+second_class_name+"]["+str(i)+"]//p[@class="+seventh_class_name+"])"
        website_type = Selector(text=data).xpath(website_type_xpath).extract()[0]
        website_type_list.append(website_type)

        revenue_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class="+first_class_name+"]//div[@class="+second_class_name+"]["+str(i)+"]//div[@class="+fifth_class_name+"]"+"//div[@class="+sixth_class_name+"][1]"+"//span[@class='shop-tile__metric__value text-bold'][1])"
        test_revenue = Selector(text=data).xpath(revenue_xpath).extract()[0]
        revenue_list.append(test_revenue)

        traffic_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class="+first_class_name+"]//div[@class="+second_class_name+"]["+str(i)+"]//div[@class="+fifth_class_name+"]"+"//div[@class="+sixth_class_name+"][2]"+"//span[@class='shop-tile__metric__value text-bold'][1])"
        test_traffic = Selector(text=data).xpath(traffic_xpath).extract()[0]
        traffic_list.append(test_traffic)

        profit_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class="+first_class_name+"]//div[@class="+second_class_name+"]["+str(i)+"]//div[@class="+fifth_class_name+"]"+"//div[@class="+sixth_class_name+"][3]"+"//span[@class='shop-tile__metric__value text-bold'][1])"
        test_profit = Selector(text=data).xpath(profit_xpath).extract()[0]
        profit_list.append(test_profit)

        inventory_value_xpath = "normalize-space(//div[@class="+first_class_name+"]//div[@class="+second_class_name+"]["+str(i)+"]//div[@class="+fifth_class_name+"]"+"//div[@class="+sixth_class_name+"][4]"+"//span[@class='shop-tile__metric__value text-bold'][1])"
        test_inventory_value = Selector(text=data).xpath(inventory_value_xpath).extract()[0]
        inventory_value_list.append(test_inventory_value)


print(len(price_list))
print(len(name_list))
print(len(website_type_list))
print(len(revenue_list))
print(len(traffic_list))
print(len(profit_list))
print(len(inventory_value_list))
```

Output:

```
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
```

Checking Lists:

```
print(price_list[:5])
print(name_list[:5])
print(website_type_list[:5])
print(revenue_list[:5])
print(traffic_list[:5])
print(profit_list[:5])
print(inventory_value_list[:5])
```

Output:

```
['$1,150USD', '$3,000USD', '$2,500USD', '$1,000USD', '$2,300USD']
['www.cosmicdetail.co.uk', 'prestige-timepiece.com', 'gomommyboutique.com', 'sunnysx.com', 'squishywishy.com']
['Automotive', 'Fashion and apparel', 'Toys and games', 'Fashion and apparel', 'Gifts and collectibles']
['$56', '$961', '$70', '$1.3K', '$403']
['111', '7.5K', '454', '2.8K', '2.6K']
['$50', '$1.0K', '$700', '$500', '$100']
['$1.8K', '', '', '', '']
```

Checking revenue's  xpath (if you want to try it on console):

```
revenue_xpath
```

Output:

```
"normalize-space(//div[@class='grid grid--equal-height']//div[@class='grid__item grid__item--tablet-up-third grid__item--desktop-up-quarter grid__item--wide-up-quarter gutter-bottom category-tile-grid-item layout-flex'][24]//div[@class='shop-tile__content shop-tile__metrics-container']//div[@class='shop-tile__metric'][1]//span[@class='shop-tile__metric__value text-bold'][1])"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have decided to implement it this way and expand on it. My question is, how do I get the Revenue for example instead of traffic? Why is it selecting traffic instead of revenue, as revenue comes first in the way you have it declared. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! I updated the code again. I also added all the table parameters and the website type.

Comment: Thank you very very much again! Sorry to be annoyning - is there any way you would be able to help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518008/selenium-load-time-errors-looking-for-possible-workaround

Answer (score 1):

To get the paragraph separately you can do somethinng like below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

weblink = 'https://exchange.shopify.com/shops?sale_price=1000&shopify_shop_created_at=6m%2C0m'

def grabData(url):
    res = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")

    for items in soup.find_all(class_="category-tile-grid-item"):
        title = items.find(class_="shop-tile__title").text
        name = items.find(class_="shop-tile__url").text
        category = items.find(class_="shop-tile__category").text
        print("{}\n{}\n{}\n".format(title,name,category))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grabData(weblink)
```

Output:

```
DIODE BRAND
diodebrand.us
Art and photography

Private listing #572131
URL Hidden
Gifts and collectibles
```