# Selenium load time errors - looking for possible workaround

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to data scrape from a certain website. I am using Selenium so that I can log myself in, and then start parsing through data.

I have 3 main errors:

- Last page # not loading properly. here I am loading "1" when it should be "197" and I believe this is happening because of the load associated with the website
- element 'test' xpath not being found properly. I commented out in last for loop.

---

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[1]/div[@class='col-lg-3 col-sm-3 result-info' and 2]/span[@class='brand-name' and 1]"}
```

---

- finally, I am trying to click last page to test if that works, but I am getting an error that Element is not found.

---

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

---

This is my code

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = "https://marketplace.refersion.com/"
username = "jupoxar@b2bx.net"
password = "testpass123"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/xxx/Downloads/chromedriver")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   driver.get(url)

   driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@class='wrapper']/div[@class='top-block']/header[@class='header clearfix']/div[@class='login-button']/a[@class='login-link']").click()

   driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(username)  # enters the username in textbox

   driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='app']/div[@class='top-block']/div[@class='row']/div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 main-section']/div[@class='main-section-content']/div/form[@class='form-horizontal']/div[@class='form-group ']/div[@class='col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 input-group input-group-lg']/input[@id='password']").send_keys(password)  # enters the password in textbox

   # Find the submit button using class name and click on it.
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("btn-primary").click()

   driver.find_element_by_link_text("Find Offers").click()

   driver.find_element_by_id("sorting-dropdown").click()  # enters the username in textbox

   driver.find_element_by_link_text("Newest First").click()

   last_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name("right-center").text
   print(last_page)

   # try:
   #     last_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'right-center')))
   #     print("Page is ready!")
   # except TimeoutException:
   #     print("Loading took too much time!")

   for i in range(1, 10):
     #   test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[1]/div[@class='col-lg-3 col-sm-3 result-info' and 2]/span[@class='brand-name' and 1]")
      #  print(test)

     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'hover-link'))).click()
```

---

I think this has to do with the way the page is being loaded. My question is, is there any work around to something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have [explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) in your code to handle the dynamic loading of the pages. Sorting the page by "Newest First" causes it to refresh the results and introduces a spinner to indicate the sorting.

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 48px;"></i>
```

Waiting for the spinner to disappear should give you the correct page count. Something on the following lines:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
.....
# your login code
.....

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Newest First").click()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//i[@class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin']"))
)
last_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name("right-center").text
```

To find all the brand names listed on the page, you need to find all the `span` tags with `class='brand-name'` by calling the method **find_elements_by_xpath**(plural, elements)

```
brand_names_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='brand-name']")
for brand_name in brand_name_list:
    print brand_name.text
```

Comment: Hi - thank you so much for your help! Got it figured out. My next question is, with regards to the last part `brand_names_list`. I have that working just fine. How do I for example pull out `affiliate fee`, `cookie days`, and `eepc`, separately as they are the same class name. Thank you!

Comment: @sgerbhctim You should ask a seperate question, since this question deals with the load times. Also, can i ask you to accept my answer?